# A property processed by a special vector field.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $Y$ be a vector field on $\mathbb R^n$ (or any Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$). When will we know that

$$Y =\nabla_X X$$

for some other vector fields $X$? Or more precisely, if $Y$ does satisfy that equality for some $X$, will $Y$ satisfy some integral equality (Some consequence of divergence theorem)?

Comment: do you know the example $C''=D_{C'}C'$ for a curve $C$ and the standard connection $D$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @janmarqz: Do you mean we have to consider the integral curve of that vector fields?

Comment: instead of solving for a general $Y$ vectorfield, solve for $\partial_k=\nabla_XX$